# elastic: search with unnecessary words

Tags: elasticsearch, query-analyzer

please show me the right direction :)

I've a task: find documents in elastic search by query, which may contain unnecessary words.

I'll show what I mean:

assume that I have some document which contains words "**big red car**" (now they are in different fields in index), and I want to find this document with a queries like: "**big** dark **red car**" or "very **big** light **red** muscule **car**" or even "the **big car** has beatiful **red** color".
But, in same time I want to save opportunity to find by "**red car**" or "**big car**"

List of unnecessary words undefined and I can't add them to stop-words.

Thank you in advance (:

Answer (score 0):

Elasticsearch has a [bool query type](http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-bool-query.html). You can add define your query with it. I won't give you an exact code. Since its look like a homework or an assignment. If you provide us what you have done so far, then i might add a working code.

But here is the pseudocode:

```
carQuery = fieldName with fieldValue 'car'
bigQuery = fieldName with fieldValue 'big'
redQuery = fieldName with fieldValue 'red'

boolQuery.must(carQuery).should(bigQuery).mustnot(redQuery)
```

I hope it will be useful.

Comment: yes, it seems that it works for me if I put all fields to a some other field **text**, then JSON for request will be this:
{
    "query": {
        "bool": {
            "should": [
             {"term": { "text": { "term": "big"}}}, 
                {"term": { "text": { "term": "red"}}}, 
                {"term": { "text": { "term": "car"}}}               
            ]
        }
    }
}